# What do generators do?

Tags: the-swindle

I just attempted a heist in The Swindle, when I came across something that looked like this:

[image]

I assume this is a generator. It looked like it could give me some cash, so I blasted through the wall to get to it. However, when I got there I couldn't interact with it. The fact that it was a generator made me think if I shut it down then it might make the level easier, so I planted a bomb next to it. As soon as it went off, I was detected. Since the game does not explain anything to the player, I have no idea what happened. What are the mechanics of generators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at there is actually a **Security Station**. Once you level up your hacking skill a few times (I cannot recall the required level off the top of my head) you will be able to hack these.

If you can successfully hack *all* the security stations on a heist, you will **disable all cameras and flying drones for that heist** (note that cameras come back online if the alarm is later triggered, although I don't think they actually matter at that stage..).

However, as you have accidentally discovered, if you damage a security station the alarm is immediately triggered. Similarly, the alarm will trip if you make a mistake while hacking a security station (by hitting the wrong direction for a prompt), so try not to rush when hacking these.